# Prevent Expand/Collapse from nested Links

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page that uses Bootstrap. In this page, I am using the Collapse component to toggle visibility of some elements. In each collapse component, I have some links and buttons. If a user clicks one of these links or buttons, I do ***NOT*** want the related content to expand collapse.

I have a Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27037/), which contains the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#parent1">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <h2>Parent 1</h2>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return onDetailsClick();">details</a></li>
        <li><button onclick="return onRunClick()">Run</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="parent1" class="collapse">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h3><small>Children</small></h3>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#parent2">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <h2>Parent 2</h2>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return onDetailsClick();">details</a></li>
        <li><button onclick="return onRunClick()">Run</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="parent2" class="collapse">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h3><small>Children</small></h3>    
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#parent3">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <h2>Parent 3</h2>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return onDetailsClick();">details</a></li>
        <li><button onclick="return onRunClick()">Run</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="parent3" class="collapse">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h3><small>Children</small></h3>    
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Somehow the event seems to be going up the chain even though I'm returning false in the event handlers. I'm not sure how to remedy this. Any help is appreciated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remove the toggle attributes of each row and start the effect manually with JavaScript, then prevent the `<button>` and `<a>` elements from taking any action.

All your code would look like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row row1">
<div class="col-xs-8">
  <h2>Parent 1</h2>     
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="#">details</a></li>
    <li><button>Run</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>  
 <div class="row" id="parent1">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
   <h3><small>Children</small></h3>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row row2">
 <div class="col-xs-8">
   <h2>Parent 2</h2>     
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="#">details</a></li>
    <li><button>Run</button></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row" id="parent2">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
   <h3><small>Children</small></h3>    
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row row3">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <h2>Parent 3</h2>     
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <ul class="list-inline">
     <li><a href="#">details</a></li>
     <li><button>Run</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="parent3">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h3><small>Children</small></h3>    
  </div>  
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    //on click in row1 class init toggle effect
    $(".row1").on("click", function(){
        //collapse content
        $("#parent1").collapse('toggle');
    });
    $("div.row2").click(function(){
        $("#parent2").collapse('toggle');
    });
    $("div.row3").click(function(){
        $("#parent3").collapse('toggle');
    });
    //on click in button or a return false
    $("button, a").on("click", function(){
         return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: But, I want the row to be the expander/collapser. I just don't want to expand / collapse if the user clicks the button. I don't want to force the user to click the `h2` element.

Comment: Oh, ok, I'll see how I can help you later.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move "collapsing attributs" to the `h2` rather than the `div` container that include you links, like that:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <h2 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#parent1">Parent 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
           <ul class="list-inline">
           <li><a href="#" onclick="return onDetailsClick();">details</a></li>
           <li><button onclick="return onRunClick()">Run</button></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the row to be the expander/collapser. I just don't want to expand / collapse if the user clicks the button. I don't want to force the user to click the `h2` element.

Comment: Have you tried to move te attributs on the "col-xs-8" div?
Either way, i belive you need to move the event from any parent element of the link/button or you'll still trigger it each time you click on one of them.